# Cypress command vs JS function

Tags: cypress

The [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-file) suggests that commands are the right way to reuse fragments of code, e.g.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("logout", () => {
  cy.get("[data-cy=profile-picture]").click();
  cy.contains("Logout").click();
});

cy.logout();
```

For simple cases like this, why would I use a command over a plain JS function (and all the nice IDE assistance that comes with it). What are the drawbacks of rewriting the above snippet as

```
export function logout(){
  cy.get("[data-cy=profile-picture]").click();
  cy.contains("Logout").click();
}

// and now somewhere in a test
logout();
```

Comment: Functions are fine as a way to group cy commands, but must be aware that they run on the main JS execution thread whereas cy commands (including custom commands) run on the Cypress queue. So if the function mixes branching or looping with commands, the process flow might not be as expected.

Comment: There's a good section in Cypress docs about this in the custom commands page. https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices

Comment: There’s no reason to add this level of complexity when you’re only wrapping a couple of commands. That means you and your team members exert much more mental effort to understand what your custom command does.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my experience with Cypress (one year project and several hundred test cases), I can say that a plan JS function is great for grouping cy commands.

From my point of view, a custom cy command may be really useful only if it is incorporated into the chain processing (utilizes the subject parameter or returns a Chainable to be used further in the chain). Otherwise, a plain JS function is preferable due to it simplicity and full IDE support (unless you're using [an additional plugin](https://youtu.be/nCIgdCcPamM)).

If you for any reason need to do something inside the cypress loop, you can always wrap you code by `cy.then()` in a plain JS function:

```js
      function myFunction() {
        cy.then(() => {
          console.log(("I'm inside the Cypress event loop"))
        })
      }
```

Comment: If you still want the feature of chaining you could just have the plain js function return the cy object.
And if you want to pass in the some context to the function, just pass the cy object as argument for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Commands are for behavior that is needed across all tests. For example, `cy.setup` or `cy.login`. Otherwise, use functions.
See official docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#1-Don-t-make-everything-a-custom-command